# Two Lists as children in a WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I have a WPF TreeView that is bound to a list of objects that has several lists in each of them.

```
public List<OwnerClass> OwnerClasses {get; set;}

public class OwnerClass
{
    public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
    public List<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
}
```

I am looking to find a way to show both lists as children of the parent.

Like this:

```
> Owner1
   |
   + SomeObject 1
   + SomeObject 2
   + SomeObject 3
   + OtherObject 1
   + OtherObject 2
   + OtherObject 3
   + OtherObject 4

> Owner2
   |
   + SomeObject 1
   + SomeObject 2
   + SomeObject 3
   + OtherObject 1
   + OtherObject 2
   + OtherObject 3
   + OtherObject 4
```

I want the treeview functionallity, but I want the child lists side by side.  (And each one as a tree view, because they in turn have lists.)

Is this possible?

Comment: Create a proper ViewModel. Transform the data in whatever format you have it to something that can be used in a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make a property that "joins" the two lists into one:

```
public class OwnerClass
{
    public List<SomeObject> SomeObjects { get; set; }
    public List<OtherObject> OtherObjects { get; set; }
    public object AllObjects 
    {
        get
        {
            List<object> list = SomeObjects;
            list.AddRange(OtherObjects);
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two things really to do this easily. The first has been demonstrated nicely by @DLeh, although I'd recommend using the `ObservableCollection<T>` class rather than the `List<T>` class when using WPF.

The second thing you need is a `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. It's like an ordinary `DataTemplate`, but it allows you to set a source for the child nodes:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type YourXmlNamespacePrefix:OwnerClass}" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllObjects}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomePropertyFromObject}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You can find out more from the [`HierarchicalDataTemplate` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.